# Service Fabric Cluster with Docker Containers with windowsservercore and iis server

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric

Am trying to create a service fabric cluster with 3 docker containers running a `windowsservercore` image and `iis` server installed on top.

I have enabled `Remote Registry Service` on all the containers and have exposed ports ranging from 135-20063 .

I am getting the following issue while creating the cluster:

> System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
>      at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPathInner(String machineName)
>      at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPath(String machineName)
>   System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
>      at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPathInner(String machineName)
>      at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPath(String machineName)
>   Machine 172.24.186.140 could not be reached for RPC. Check network connectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>   Machine 172.28.166.142 could not be reached for RPC. Check network connectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>   System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
>      at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPathInner(String machineName)
>      at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.GetTempPath(String machineName)
>   Machine 172.25.205.155 could not be reached for RPC. Check network connectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>   Create Cluster failed. For more information please look at traces in FabricLogRoot.
>   Create Cluster failed with exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateExcep
>   tion: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: Machine 172.24.186.140 could not be reached for RPC. Chec
>   k network connectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.b__5f(String machine)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallel
>   Options, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOption
>   s, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithE
>   verything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.CheckRPCAccess(IEnumerable`1 machineNames)
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabric
>   PackageSourcePath, Boolean rollbackOnFailure)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: Machine 17
>   2.24.186.140 could not be reached for RPC. Check network connectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CheckRPCAccess>b__5f(String machine)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallel
>   Options, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOption
>   s, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithE
>   verything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.CheckRPCAccess(IEnumerable`1 machineNames)
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.d__a.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.IOException: Machine 172.24.186.140 could not be reached for RPC. Check network conn
>   ectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.b__5f(String machine)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )<---
>
> ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.IO.IOException: Machine 172.28.166.142 could not be reached for RPC. Check network conn
>   ectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.b__5f(String machine)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )<---
>
> ---> (Inner Exception #2) System.IO.IOException: Machine 172.25.205.155 could not be reached for RPC. Check network conn
>   ectivity. HRESULT=53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH
>      at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.b__5f(String machine)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )<---
>   <---

Answer (score 0):

It's showing RPC is closed from your controller to  172.28.166.142. Try "test-netconnection  172.28.166.142 -port 135"